# Sample server & client for Rack hijack proxy questions

Tags: ruby, rack

I've got [sample app](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/cabe6b33ca4601aa6acb56317ac1c819cf6dc4bb/test/spec_webrick.rb#L162-L183) for hijack proxy server

```
io_lambda = lambda{ |io|
      3.times do |i|
        puts i
        io.write "David\r\n"
      end
      io.close
    }

run lambda{ |req|
      [
        200,
        [ [ "rack.hijack", io_lambda ] ],
        [""]
      ]
    }
```

and starting it

```
rackup config.ru -p 3000
```

Now I trying to code client for it. First, just curl it:

```
curl http://localhost:3000 -vv
```

and get following client output:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:3000/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
David
David
* transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

now, with httparty:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default)

response = HTTParty.get('http://localhost:3000')
puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
```

I get:

```
→ ruby httparty-client.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
    19: from httparty-client.rb:5:in `<main>'
    18: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/httparty-0.17.1/lib/httparty.rb:627:in `get'
    17: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/httparty-0.17.1/lib/httparty.rb:508:in `get'
    16: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/httparty-0.17.1/lib/httparty.rb:594:in `perform_request'
    15: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/httparty-0.17.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:145:in `perform'
    14: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1470:in `request'
    13: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:920:in `start'
    12: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1472:in `block in request'
    11: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1479:in `request'
    10: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1517:in `transport_request'
     9: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:166:in `reading_body'
     8: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:229:in `body'
     7: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:204:in `read_body'
     6: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:283:in `read_body_0'
     5: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:278:in `inflater'
     4: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:285:in `block in read_body_0'
     3: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:324:in `read_chunked'
     2: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:324:in `ensure in read_chunked'
     1: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:159:in `read'
/Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:225:in `rbuf_fill': end of file reached (EOFError)
```

last try with net/http:

```
require 'net/http'

streamURL = 'http://localhost:3000'

uri = URI.parse(streamURL)

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri

  http.request request do |response|
    response.read_body do |chunk|
       #We get the data here chunk-by-chunk
       puts chunk
    end
  end
end
```

I get:

```
→ ruby net-http-client.rb
David
David
David
David
Traceback (most recent call last):
    16: from net-http-client.rb:7:in `<main>'
    15: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:605:in `start'
    14: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:920:in `start'
    13: from net-http-client.rb:10:in `block in <main>'
    12: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1479:in `request'
    11: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1517:in `transport_request'
    10: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:165:in `reading_body'
     9: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1518:in `block in transport_request'
     8: from net-http-client.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
     7: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:204:in `read_body'
     6: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:283:in `read_body_0'
     5: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:278:in `inflater'
     4: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:285:in `block in read_body_0'
     3: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:324:in `read_chunked'
     2: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:324:in `ensure in read_chunked'
     1: from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:159:in `read'
/Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:225:in `rbuf_fill': end of file reached (EOFError)
```

Could someone explain me:

1) Why curl return David x2,  httparty - nothing and net/http - David x4, while server sent 5? Also I'm curious why httparty and net/http results differ, because one uses another under the hood.

2) Why in all cases we have an error (`transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining` and `end of file reached (EOFError)`)?

Comment: If you're trying to implement SSE, **don't hijack the socket**. Use an SSE enabled Ruby application Server (such as agoo or iodine). If you hijack the socket, you might find your app failing once HTTP/2 is implemented and you won't even know where to find the bug (they get difficult to track down at that point).

Answer (score 0):

Have figured it out. Headers do matter. This version makes it work for all clients

```
io_lambda = lambda{ |io|
      5.times do |i|
        puts i
        io.write "David\r\n"
        sleep 1
      end
      io.close
    }

app = lambda do |env|

  response_headers = {}
  response_headers['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary'
  response_headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain"
  response_headers["rack.hijack"] = io_lambda
  [200, response_headers, nil]

end

run app
```